# How to connect Webcam USB Audio to Jack - Carla - UBUNTU STUDIO

Tags: webcam, ubuntu-studio, audio-jack

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 with a presonus USB audio Interface working fine. But I really need capture audio from USB Webcams and send to jack/carla. Some foruns say that the webcam should show up in Carla as a Device, but nothing besides my USB Presonus appears at Carla Patchbay. How can I use multiples USB audio devices in Ubuntu Studio?